# jquery how to decrease number of cols in textarea based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea with the default number of columns, like 10 or 15 or something. I want the text area to shrinkwrap the text inside on blur. Does anyone know how to do this?

So far I have

```
$('textarea').live('blur', function() {
    var textAreaWidth = $(this).val().length;
    $(this).attr('cols', 'textAreaWidth');

});
```

But this is ugly for obvious reasons. I just have no clue how to do this.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to only decrease the size you should check that if the value is less than, say 20 and then decrease the number of columns. try this:

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>

$('textarea').on('blur', function() {
    var textAreaWidth = $(this).val().length;

    if (textAreaWidth < 20) {
       $(this).attr('cols', textAreaWidth);
    }
    $('textarea').on('keypress', function() {
       $(this).attr('cols', '20');
    });   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bccm/

Comment: good idea to add the if statement, I was thinking of that, however the original problem still exists. Like if i put in 1 character, the text box actually gets longer. Idk whats going on

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes from around 'textAreaWidth' in

`$(this).attr('cols', 'textAreaWidth');`

This is a variable and doesn't need quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').bind('blur keyup', function() {
    $(this).attr('cols', $(this).val().length);
});​
```

This makes it shrink or grow as you type/blur.